# How to redirect api requests to express port on WAMP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, wamp

I have a React app making requests to an express api server which is running on port 9000.
In dev I use a proxy setting in my package.json which works as expected:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:9000/"
```

I have now built and deployed both the api and the client and have deployed them both to the www folder on WAMP. The api is working fine as I can interact with it using Postman. The client is also up and running however it is now trying to call the api on the wrong port:

```
http://localhost/api/...
```

How can I redirect the api requests to port 9000 on WAMP?

```
http://localhost:9000/api/...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to remove the proxy setting and prefix the requests with the correct api domain. This way it works as expected on both dev and prod:

```
private domain = "http://localhost:9000";

get(url: string, params?: any): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const result = await trackPromise(
        axios.get(this.domain + url, { params: params })
      );
      return resolve(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      return reject(error.response.data.message);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proxy feature is not for the production. It is meant to be used for development only. Proxy in development is just a productivity feature. It’s useful if you serve the single-page app from your API server in production, but want to use the development server provided by `create-react-app` while you work on the app. However proxy is just that: a development feature. It is not meant for production.

You can read more about it [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/). If you really want to point a port, add it to `app.js` of your node application and consider starting server on that port.